# jQuery word count on each entry

Tags: jquery, count

I'm working on a blog theme that has a word count for each entry on the side of every post. I can get the word count to work, but it only works on the first entry, and then displays the same count for every post. I need to modify the script below to find the closest `div.entrycontent` and count the words in it, but for every entry. Below is my entry markup code, if anyone could help it'd be appreciated.

```
<div class="entry">
    <div class="entryinfo">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var text = $('.entrycontent').text();
            var wordCount = text.split(' ').length;
            $("span.words").text(wordCount + ' words');
        </script>
        <span class="words"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="entrycontent">
        Lorem ipsum dolor amet...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems to me as though you should do the word count on the server and probably store it in the DB, counting the words every time your page is displayed seems wasteful.

Comment: Where's your `<char id="chars">` ?

Comment: Quick suggestion: place a generic script at the bottom of the page. If you want your word count to be dynamic, then you'll need to set an event listener on `keypress`. You can get the current element by looking at the element on `focus`.

Comment: @NathanKoop this website isn't running on a database, this is a tumblr blog so I need to use jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through using `.each()`.

Put this script once on the page, either at the bottom or at the top inside a `$(document).ready(function(){...});` block:

```
$('.entry').each(function(i,el) {
    var $entry = $(this),
        text = $entry.find('.entrycontent').text(),
        wordCount = text.split(' ').length;
    $entry.find("span.words").text(wordCount + ' words');
    $entry.find("span.chars").text(charCount); // IDs must be unique, use classes instead
});
```

**UPDATE**

When `$entry.find('.entrycontent').text()` contains a lot of whitespace, it's splitting on each of those space characters whether it separates a word or not. Try this:

```
$('.entry').each(function(i,el) {
    var $entry = $(this),
        text = $entry.find('.entrycontent').text(),
        wordCount = text.split(/\s+/).length;
    $entry.find("span.words").text(wordCount + ' words');
});
```

[`.split()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

**UPDATE 2**

Well, if you want a true word count, I suppose that we should use [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of `.split()`:

```
$('.entry').each(function(i,el) {
    var $entry = $(this),
        text = $entry.find('.entrycontent').text(),
        marr = text.match(/\w+/g) || [],  // null if no matches
        wordCount = marr.length;
    $entry.find("span.words").text(wordCount + ' words');
});
```

Comment: This worked the best, but the count is off.. It's saying picture posts have 222 words when they actually have 0... I think it may be counting HTML which is a problem.

Comment: Hard to know without seeing actual code. Reread the [.text() docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and see if that points you in the right direction.

Comment: I just read an article about that but now it's displaying "1 words"

Comment: That makes sense -- it's the length of the array after splitting. Let's try using `.match` instead....

Comment: This displays nothing... let's go to chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11750/discussion-between-jamescharless-and-blazemonger)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.entry').each(function() {
 var text = $(".entrycontent", this).text(),
     wordCount = text.split(/\s+/).length;
 $("span.words", this).text(wordCount + ' words');
 $("span#chars", this).text(charCount);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably has something to do with your selector being tied to any element that has a class of entrycontent.

I would recommend iterating over each entry like so:

```
$(".entrycontent").each(function() {
    var entryInfo = $(this).prev();
    var text = $(this).text(); 
    var wordCount = text.split(' ').length;  
    entryInfo.find("span.words").text(wordCount + ' words');  
});
```